# add mute line to contextual menu

Tags: .net, winforms, cefsharp, mute

i am working with Cefsharp and winforms to deploy a webview control.

I have add some lines to contextual menu but i need add mute line to contextual menu in Cefsharp implementation:

Natives:

```
model.Clear();
model.AddItem(CefMenuCommand.Copy, "Copy (Ctrl + C)");
model.AddItem(CefMenuCommand.Paste, "Paste (Ctrl + V)");
model.AddSeparator();
model.AddItem(CefMenuCommand.Reload, "Refresh Windows (F5)");
```

Custom:

```
model.AddItem((CefMenuCommand)26505, "New Windows (Ctrl+N)");
```

natives no need implementation but custom need a little more code:

```
if (commandId == (CefMenuCommand)26505)
{
 // New Windows Implementation
}
```

I can't find a way to programmatically turn off the audio for the current navigation control from contextual menu, Can someone help me?

mine docs: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/pull/3248

Comment: http://cefsharp.github.io/api/90.6.x/html/M_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_SetAudioMuted.htm
http://cefsharp.github.io/api/90.6.x/html/P_CefSharp_IBrowserHost_IsAudioMuted.htm

Comment: @amaitland the version still not reaching the nuget package manager

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.